# Will adding a constant to a random variable change its distribution?

Tags: probability, measure-theory

Suppose I have a random variable $X$ and to this, I add a constant $c>0$. Will $X+c$ have a different distribution? From my intuition it seems so, but I am unable to prove it from a measure-theoretic point of view. Does the proof require measure theory? Thanks!

Comment: Certainly. In some cases (example, normal) it will stay in the same family, and in other cases (Poisson) it will not. To see that the distributions are always different, note that the cdf changes.

Comment: I came up with a proof, $F(x) = P(X \leq x)$. Now, $P(X+c \leq x) = P(X \leq x-c)$, which doesnt equal the original, we shifted the distribution, would this suffice as a proof?

Comment: Not quite. It is perfectly possible to have an $x$ such that $\Pr(X\le x)=\Pr(X\le x-c)$. This indeed happens often. In a Poisson  distribution we have $\Pr(X\le -3)=\Pr(X\le -7)$.  Also, $\Pr(X\le 1.8)=\Pr(X\le 1.5)$. But you can show that for any distribution, **there exists** an $x$ such that $\Pr(X\le x)\ne \Pr(X\le x-c)$.

Comment: Or else if you are in a very fancy mood, you can use characteristic functions. If $c\ne 0$, then the expectation of $e^{itX}$ is different from the expectation of $e^{itX+itc}$ if $t\ne 0$.

Comment: I see, so if I wanted to show the case for c=1, that it is NOT the case that $X \sim X+1$, would my above proof work with $P(X+1 \leq x) = P(X \leq x-1)$?

Comment: Sure, for $x$  positive, in the Poisson case. But you want to prove it for all non-zero $c$, and all distributions.

Comment: I read somewhere that it was impossible to have the case of $X ~ X+1$ for any distribution, so to prove this, would I need to use something more fancy than what I had above?

Comment: I have written out a proof that $X$ and $X+c$ never have the same distribution if $c\gt 0$.  Basically the same idea works also for $c\lt 0$. In particular, $X$ and $X+1$ never have the same distribution.

Answer (score 4):

I feel like I'm making a huge mistake because of how simple this feels, but...

If $X$ and $X+c$ had the same law, they would have the same expectation. But alas, $\Bbb E [X + c] = \Bbb E X + c$ so unless $c=0$, they have different laws.

Comment: Good idea. Unfortunately, not all random variables have an expectation.  But certainly your argument gives a very nice proof when the expectation of $X$ exists.

Comment: D'oh, and thats why we use characteristic functions. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

Let $c\gt 0$. We will show that $X$ and $X+c$ never have the same distribution, because they have different cumulative distribution functions.  We will show this by showing that there is a positive $h\lt c$ and a number $x$, such that $\Pr(X\le x+h)\ne \Pr(X\le x)$, and therefore $\Pr(X\le x-c)\ne \Pr(X\le x)$.

For if $F(t)$ is the cumulative distribution function of $X$, then $\lim_{t\to-\infty} F(t)=0$ and $\lim_{t\to\infty} F(t)=1$. So there is an $a$ such that $F(a)\lt 1/4$ and a $b$ such that $F(b)\gt 3/4$. By stepping forward from $a$ by steps of length $h$, we can get beyond $b$ in a finite number of steps. If we always had $F(t+h)=F(t)$, we would have $F(c)=F(a)\lt 1/4$ for some $c\gt b$, which is impossible.

Answer (score 2):

Let $Y=aX+b$; a linear transformation.   The distribution of the random variable $Y$ can then be said to have the same shape as that of $X$, but with a change of **scale** and a **shift** of ordinates.   Thus while it clearly is not the same distribution (unless $a=1 \wedge b=0$), it is the same *family of distribution*.

Eg: $X_1\sim \mathcal U(c; d)$ then $aX_1+b \sim \mathcal U(ac+b; ad+b)$

Eg: $X_2\sim\mathcal N(\mu, \sigma^2)$ then $aX_2+b \sim\mathcal N(a\mu+b, a^2\sigma^2)$

Etc…

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $X\sim N(0,1)$.  Then $\Pr(-1<X<1) \approx 0.68$ but $\Pr(-1<X+3<1) <0.03$.

So $X$ and $X+3$ have different distributions.